# Google Geo location, could it be this easy?

Tags: php, url, geolocation, maps

you see, when i type in a geo location on google maps, i end up with the url

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=55.403755999999994,+10.40237

and i need to find all the gas stations near it, so ofcourse i will press ' Nearby ' and type in Gas station, but then i end up with a deformed URL being

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=gas+station&sll=55.403756,10.40237&sspn=0.010027,0.01929&near=Kochsgade+47B,+5000+Odense,+Danmark&geocode=CVvcdG1J0vHwFbllTQMdvLmeAClLHi4PAiBNRjGyrpFlhkir-w&t=h&hq=gas+station&z=13

My question is, would i be able to have a clean url so i can link it easily to the user that is on the site and show him the gas stations nearby him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=gas+station&sll=55.403756,10.40237

```
q=gas+station          //What
sll=55.403756,10.40237 //Where
```

The rest of the parameters aren't required.

Comment: Sorry for seeming dumb, but https://maps.google.com/maps?q=gas+station&sll=55.403756,10.40237&hq=gas+station
q=gas+station  won't it then search for Gas station, and not the SLL?

Comment: Click the link, for me it's showing gas stations near those coordinates.

Comment: Yea, I had a `&hq=gas+station` still in there.
If this is the answer, would you want to mark it as such, please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a URL shortener. There are many

[bitly.com](http://bitly.com)

Or try [this](http://yourls.org/)

Comment: I don't mind the url being long, but i need to pull his geo location out, and then link his location into the URL so that the user can see the nearby gas stations

Comment: That would mean a additional api call to construct a shortened url that really isn't necessary, unless you want someone to remember, or manually copy the url (As in read -> type)